# Create XML Data on iOS for Web Service Request

Tags: xml, ios4

On the desktop I prepare the web service request payload in an NSXMLDocument.  On iOS there is no NSXMLDocument.  What approaches have folks used to include XML in the payload of a web service request on iOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've looked at [TouchXML](http://github.com/schwa/TouchXML), [KissXML](http://code.google.com/p/kissxml/) and have settled on using [GDataXML](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/) (part of the Google Objective C client library).